# Using htaccess to block banned IPs from site but allow them to access one particular file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, pattern-matching, http-status-code-403, ip-blocking

Haven't managed to find any answers to this at StackOverflow, so here goes:

I have a long list of banned IPs that I would like to block from my website entirely, but I would like to redirect them all to a special customized (not general-purpose) 403 forbidden message on the site. Is there a way to accomplish this via htaccess?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this,

```
RewriteEngine On    
#ip addresses to block
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^111\.11\.111\.111$
RewriteRule ^ file.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! I was secretly hoping for a solution that wouldn't involve using pattern matching, so as to avoid ^ $ and \. ;-) Is there a way to do this using:
<files MATCHparameters>
order allow,deny
deny from 1.2.3.4
</files>
?
(Sorry, the line breaks aren't showing up in this comment)
Thanks!

Comment: @Abhisek: To clarify: I want to direct these specific banned IPs to a specific page, not a general error page. Also, I've been trying to block myself using RewriteRule method, but I still get through -- my server doesn't seem to respond to this method.